# Select query with multiple like conditions in Sql

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

All,

I have a view from which some filtered data is to be fetched by sql query

View structure:

```
BridgeId      int
Name          varchar
DisplayName   varchar
```

There is a search text box in which user can enter any one of the values for filtering.

due to project old framework i have to query from c# itself.

```
public static List<ConferenceBridges> GetSearchList(string search)
        {
            DB db = new DB(SERVER_NAME, DATA_BASE_NAME);
            string searchQuery = string.Format("select BridgeId,Name,OwnerId from vConferenceBridgesDetails where BridgeId like '%' + {0} + '%' OR Name like'%' + {0} + '%' OR DisplayName like '%' + {0} + '%'", search);
            DataTable table = db.GetData(searchQuery);
            List<ConferenceBridges> bridgeList = new List<ConferenceBridges>();
            if (table != null && table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow item in table.Rows)
                {
                    bridgeList.Add(new ConferenceBridges(item));
                }
            }
            return bridgeList;
        }
```

the problems : 
when ever i enter a bridge id it is int but passed as string so it give error and for string values it give invalid column name.

How can i make the query so that it accept all the parameters.

Comment: parameterized the values.

Comment: this: `'%' + {0} + '%'` should be `'%{0}%'`,  also its would be better to use prepared statements

Comment: can't parmeterized for the sake of consistency,legacy app :(

Comment: i have return the query in sql editor so it was like that i have changed this worked for all the cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'%' + {0} + '%'` is just wrong.

if `search = "abc"`
this would generate: `"Name like '%'+abc+'%'"` which is obviously invalid sql

if you use `'%{0}%'` instead, you will have valid sql (if there is no `'` in `search`)

use this:

```
string searchQuery = string.Format("select BridgeId,Name,OwnerId from vConferenceBridgesDetails where BridgeId like '%{0}%' OR Name like '%{0}%' OR DisplayName like '%{0}%'", search);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, BridgeId  is an int and like cannot be implemented on int so either change it to varchar or use =

**Secondly**, whereever you are using like statement you have to pass it with single quotes like

```
string searchQuery = string.Format("select BridgeId,Name,OwnerId from vConferenceBridgesDetails where BridgeId  =  {0}  OR Name like '% + {0} + %' OR DisplayName like '% + {0} + %'", search);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `'%YourValue%`' inplace of `'%' + YourValue + '%'` aditional `'` and `+` sign is causing the issue.